# How to update a dict inside a list

Tags: python, django

I have the following `list` in my view context, which contains `dictionaries`:

```
[{ < CustomUser: admin@admin.com >: [
            {
                'label': 'ID',
                'value': 1,
            }]
},
{ < CustomUser: admin2@admin.com >: [
    {
        'label': 'ID',
        'value': 4,
    }]
}]
```

I want to merge each `dict` in the list with the following `dict`:

```
{ < CustomUser: admin @admin.com >:
    {
        'role': 'Company 1'
    }, 
  < CustomUser: admin2 @admin.com >:
    {
        'role': 'Company 2'
    }
}
```

So that this is the end result:

```
[{ < CustomUser: admin@admin.com >: [
            {
                'label': 'ID',
                'value': 1,
                'role': 'Company 1'
            }]
},
{ < CustomUser: admin2@admin.com >: [
    {
        'label': 'ID',
        'value': 4,
        'role': 'Company 2'
    }]
}]
```

Is there any way to update `dict` inside a `list`?

I have a lot of key value pairs in reality, so can't do this manually with named fields.

Comment: why are you doing this on data level? Couldn't you do this easily via database relations and django orm!

Comment: @ans2human do you mean in a for loop in a template? I am trying to create a DRY approach to generic template generation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're getting this data from a table called `CustomUser` which has these objects wherein you wish to update those objects right? so my suggestion is why don't you implement another table and feed it with data which you wish to add in `CustomUser` object. Just connect both with Foreignkey or any suitable relationship and use orm to get collective data.

Comment: This looks like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).